# How to convert a passed String to a jQuery Object?

Tags: jquery, string

**significant UPDATE**

```
doFade(paddleID);   // = "gamePaddle"

function doFade(objStrID) {

    $(document).ready(function() {

        var queryObj = $("#" + objStrID);
    
        queryObj.fadeOut(3000);

    });   // $(document).ready(function() {

}   // doFade
```

Keyvan and Lalalena, I found my problem ...

As long as my .html has at the top level:

```
<img id="gamePaddle" src="Game_1_Support/images/king.gif" alt="paddle" />
```

all of your patient guidance works!!

**But** ... my .html has:

```
<canvas id="gameBoard">

<img id="gamePaddle" src="Game_1_Support/images/king.gif" alt="paddle" />

</canvas>
```

zero!

So, the problem appeas to be the buried placement of my `img` "gamePaddle" inside of another `div`, "canvas"

Hopefully, your patience has not been exhausted with me?

I have tried to insert this needed correction via:

```
doFade("#gameBoard > #gamePaddle");
```

**and**

```
function doFade(objStrID) {

    $(document).ready(function() {

        var queryObj = $(objStrID);
    
        queryObj.fadeOut(3000);

    });

}   // doFade
```

... still zero

**end UPDATE**

How do I convert a passed String to a jQuery Object?

**HTML**

```
<img id="gamePaddle" src="Game_1_Support/images/king.gif" alt="paddle" />
```

Here's my **JS** -- I call doFade("#gamePaddle")

```
function doFade(objectID) {

//  var theObject = document.getElementById(objectID);

//  alert(typeof objectID === 'string' || objectID instanceof String);   // true
//  alert($(objectID))   // [object Object]

    $(objectID).fadeOut(3000);
    
}   // doFade
```

I have also tried hard-coding and failed:

```
$("#gamePaddle").fadeOut(3000);
```

Obviously, I am doing something wrong and my hunch is that it's very basic -- I need some help here, if you please.

Comment: Please try this : doFade('#gamePaddle')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this :

```
function doFade(objectID) {

//  var theObject = document.getElementById(objectID);

//  alert(typeof objectID === 'string' || objectID instanceof String);   // true
//  alert($(objectID))   // [object Object]

    $(objectID).fadeOut(3000);
    
}   // 

doFade('#gamePaddle')
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2nuo83cm/

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. Are you sure you have included jQuery properly, and do you call the function in either document.ready or another event listener?

```js
function doFade(objectID) {
    $(`#${objectID}`).fadeOut(3000);
}
    
$(document).ready(function() {
    doFade('gamePaddle');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="gamePaddle" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/07/30/18/26/surface-4373559_960_720.jpg" alt="paddle">
```